# Positioning div to top right of parent div won't work

Tags: css

I have a parent div `<section>` and I want to add a few icons using Font Awesome to the top right of it, so I try to give them `position:absolute` with `top:5px` and `right:5px`, but it goes to the top right of the entire page, and not of the section. (I want it to be at the top right of the yellow background, and whenever I decide to add more icons, they should be one near each other there too)

**Must view snippet in expanded mode to see the problem

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="columns">
  <div class="column is-three-fifths is-offset-one-fifth">
    <section class="section" style="border:1px solid black;background-color:yellow;">
      <div class="top_right">
        <i class="fas fa-cog" style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:5px;"></i>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the second snippet, where I want the settings icon and more icons to appear:

Comment: Put `position:relative;` in your style on `section`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `position: relative;` to the `style` attribute in `section`.

This will position the `section` element *relative* to its *parent*.

I made you a JSFiddle which can be found here:

https://jsfiddle.net/sfvLk8yL/

Answer (score 0):

you need to add position:relative to parent of absolute positioned element

Answer (score 0):

Make the position of the tag containing the div tag to position relative.The  absolute position  positions itself relative to the ancestor with the relative positioning.

Here make the position of the **section:relative**